Remove CUDA from Ubuntu 20.04
I followed the instructions on NVIDIA's website to install CUDA 11.8. I also edited the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables. Additionally, I attempted several methods to remove CUDA 12.4, as there is a conflict between the two versions, but I still see CUDA 12.4 on my system, and I can't seem to remove it.  Currently, I am unable to use the GPU.
(base) mehrdad@mehrdad-Z790-AORUS-ELITE-AX:~$ nvidia-smi
Thu Dec 19 10:49:46 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.216.03             Driver Version: 535.216.03   CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090        Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  Off |
|  0%   44C    P8               8W / 450W |    528MiB / 24564MiB |     11%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1460      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          412MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2290      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                        105MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

(base) mehrdad@mehrdad-Z790-AORUS-ELITE-AX:~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:33:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0
(base) mehrdad@mehrdad-Z790-AORUS-ELITE-AX:~$ 


How did you install cuda and how did you remove it?

The nvidia-smi cuda number shown is what it supports, not what is actually installed. Do you have any other evidence that cuda 12.4 is installed? Did you edit your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to pick up a new install?

Thank you for your response. I followed the instructions on NVIDIA's website to install CUDA 11.8. I also edited the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables. Additionally, I attempted several methods to remove CUDA 12.4, as there is a conflict between the two versions. Currently, I am unable to use the GPU.
